# Sending order form to mail with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I picked up a javascript order form (for people to command products) and implemented it in my website. I tried to create a php file sending the form contents to my mail address, but I'm stuck and google won't help me out anymore... For testing, I only defined the last three format fields in the php file, Nom (=name), Mobile and Subtotal.

The whole source code (javascript is in the html file, so it's quite large) can be found here: source

Here's just the form code, followed by the code in the "send_mail.php" file:

```
    <form name="ordform" method="post" action="send_mail.php"" style="padding-top: 200px">
<table align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#800000"><tr>
<th width="192" BGCOLOR="YELLOW"><b>Produit</b></th>
<th width="72" BGCOLOR="YELLOW" align="center"><b>Qté</b></th>
<th width="120" BGCOLOR="YELLOW" align="center"><b>Prix par unité</b></th>
<th width="120" BGCOLOR="YELLOW" align="center"><b>Prix total</b></th>
</tr>
<script language="JavaScript"><!-- 
for (var rownum=1;rownum<=RowsInForm;rownum++) {
   document.write('<tr><td width=192 BGCOLOR="CYAN">')
   document.write('<select name="prodchosen'+rownum+'" onChange="updateRow('+rownum+')">')
   for (i=0; i<=ProductsInList; i++) {
      document.write ("<option>"+prodlist[i].name)
   }
   document.write ('</select></td>')
   document.write ('<td width=72 align="center" BGCOLOR="CYAN"><input class="num" name="qty'+rownum+'" value=""')
   document.write ('size=3 onChange="updateRow('+rownum+')"></td>')
   document.write ('<td width=120 align="center" BGCOLOR="CYAN">')
   document.write ('<input class="num" name="unitprice'+rownum+'" value="" ')
   document.write ('size=10 onfocus="this.blur()"></td>')
   document.write ('<td width=120 align="center" BGCOLOR="CYAN">')
   document.write ('<input class="num" name="extprice'+rownum+'" value="" ')
   document.write ('size=10 onfocus = "this.blur()"></td>')
   document.write ('</tr>')
}
//--></script>
<tr>
<label for="subtotal"><td width="384" colspan="3" align="right" BGCOLOR="YELLOW">Total:</td></label>
<td width="120" align="center" BGCOLOR="YELLOW"><input class="num" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" size="10" onfocus="this.blur()"></td></tr>
<tr>
<label for="Nom"><td width="384" colspan="3" align="right" BGCOLOR="YELLOW">Nom:</td></label>
<td width="120" align="center" BGCOLOR="YELLOW"><input type="text" name="Nom" id="Nom" size="10"></td></tr>
<tr>
<label for="Mobile"><td width="384" colspan="3" align="right" BGCOLOR="YELLOW">Mobile:</td></label>
<td width="120" align="center" BGCOLOR="YELLOW"><input type="text" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" size="10"></td></tr>
</table>
<center>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Envoyer">
<input type="reset" value="Effacer"></center></form>

<?php
$to = "vanackerjeroen@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Kaz Order";
$Nom = $_REQUEST['Nom'];
$Mobile = $_REQUEST['Mobile'];
$subtotal = $_REQUEST['subtotal'];

$headers = "From: $Nom"; 
$fullmessage = " nom: {$Nom}\n tel: {$Mobile}\n subtotal: {$subtotal}";
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $fullmessage, $headers);
header('Location: index.html');
?>
```

Comment: page url = http://zotcreation.com/kaza/contact.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP you can catch these inside of the `send_mail.php` file (since this if the action of the form)

with the following in the top of your PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    .... any other variable.

    // send mail function using the above variables.
}
```

or instead of `nom` any other variable you posted.

i would also place the bottom php inside the if since you only want to use those if someone has send a post request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
[link](http://zotcreation.com/kaza/contact.html)
I loaded it up, the .php is now showing blank page, but no mail was received and no redirect to index.html
The if and else stuff are for later, when the script works :)

Comment: Alright! I now received a mail, redirection is fine as well, so can continue from here on. Many thanks for your time and effort :-)